# SCons: compiling generated .java files doesn't check if they are part of a package

Tags: java, build, scons

I'm pretty sure this is a bug, and I've already sent it in to the SCons user mailing list; I'm posting to ask for possible workarounds while I wait for it to be fixed, or clarification that this isn't a bug and how I'm supposed to work around it.

I've got a minimal case to reproduce the bug, though, with 2 files, SConstruct and src/Hello/World/HelloWorld.java.

I'm using SCons 3.0.0, with Python 2.7, on Windows 10.

src/Hello/World/HelloWorld.java:

```
package Hello.World;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }

}
```

SConstruct:

```
env = Environment( tools = ['javac'] )

# java
env.Append( JAVAVERSION = '1.8' )
env.Append( JAVA_HOME = 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_152' )
env.AppendENVPath( 'PATH', 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin' )

##### directories
src = Dir( 'src' )
build = Dir( 'build' )
classDir = build.Dir( 'classes' )

##### functions
srcJava = src.File( 'Hello/World/HelloWorld.java' )
copiedJava = build.File( 'Hello/World/HelloWorld.java' )

builtJava = env.Command( target = copiedJava, source = srcJava,
                         action = Copy( '$TARGET', '$SOURCE' ) )

classes = env.Java( target = classDir, source = builtJava )
```

HelloWorld.java gets copied into another build directory with env.Command() running Copy(), then the copied .java file gets put in env.Java(). The build works, and build/classes/Hello/World/HelloWorld.class gets created properly, but running SCons again yields an issue.

```
C:/example> scons --debug=explain -Q
scons: building `build\classes\HelloWorld.class' because it doesn't exist
javac -d build\classes -sourcepath build\Hello\World build\Hello\World\HelloWorld.java
```

The SCons node is pointing in the wrong location. The reason this happens is because of the Javac emitter.

On line 96/97 of SCons/Tool/javac.py:

```
if not f.is_derived():
        pkg_dir, classes = parse_java_file(f.rfile().get_abspath(), version)
```

These two lines essentially mean that the java file only gets parsed for things like import statements if the source file is considered 'not derived.' I simulate this in my example by copying the file, but it's a huge issue in practice if you have any generated .java files in a project.

As for workarounds I've looked into so far, trying to access the is_derived() attribute of a file is very difficult, with a lot of read-only functions that essentially check if a node has builders. The Java builder doesn't seem to take .class files as target arguments, so I can't fix it by being more explicit.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Are there clever workarounds I haven't thought of? For now, I'm just changing that if statement in Tool/javac.py to 'if True:' until I can excise the package structure from this part of the project.

——— Update ———

As bdbaddog pointed out, my 'if True:' fix didn't work; as soon as the generated file was gone, SCons would try to parse the file before it had been built. Errors ensue.

Since then, I've created my own version of Tool/javac.py, which I called JavaFix.py, which resets the Java() builder with a slightly improved emitter. Most of the file is the same, so I'll just post the updated emitter and helper function:

```
def findComDir(entry):
    """Return a node representing the base of the source tree.
    Assumes that the first module of the package is named 'com.'
    """
    node = entry
    while node.name != 'com':
        node = node.dir
        if ':' in node.name:
            return entry
    return node


def emit_java_classes(target, source, env):
    """Create and return lists of source java files
    and their corresponding target class files.
    """
    java_suffix = env.get('JAVASUFFIX', '.java')
    class_suffix = env.get('JAVACLASSSUFFIX', '.class')

    target[0].must_be_same(SCons.Node.FS.Dir)
    classdir = target[0]

    s = source[0].rentry().disambiguate()
    if isinstance(s, SCons.Node.FS.File):
        comDir = findComDir(s)
        sourcedir = comDir.dir.rdir()
    elif isinstance(s, SCons.Node.FS.Dir):
        sourcedir = s.rdir()
    else:
        raise SCons.Errors.UserError("Java source must be File or Dir, not '%s'" % s.__class__)

    slist = []
    js = _my_normcase(java_suffix)
    for entry in source:
        entry = entry.rentry().disambiguate()
        if isinstance(entry, SCons.Node.FS.File):
            slist.append(entry)
        elif isinstance(entry, SCons.Node.FS.Dir):
            result = SCons.Util.OrderedDict()
            dirnode = entry.rdir()
            def find_java_files(arg, dirpath, filenames):
                java_files = sorted([n for n in filenames
                                     if _my_normcase(n).endswith(js)])
                mydir = dirnode.Dir(dirpath)
                java_paths = [mydir.File(f) for f in java_files]
                for jp in java_paths:
                    arg[jp] = True
            for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dirnode.get_abspath()):
                find_java_files(result, dirpath, filenames)
            entry.walk(find_java_files, result)

            slist.extend(list(result.keys()))
        else:
            raise SCons.Errors.UserError("Java source must be File or Dir, not '%s'" % entry.__class__)

    version = env.get('JAVAVERSION', '1.4')
    full_tlist = []
    for f in slist:
        tlist = []
        source_file_based = True
        pkg_dir = None
        if not f.is_derived():
            pkg_dir, classes = parse_java_file(f.rfile().get_abspath(), version)
            if classes:
                source_file_based = False
                if pkg_dir:
                    d = target[0].Dir(pkg_dir)
                    p = pkg_dir + os.sep
                else:
                    d = target[0]
                    p = ''
                for c in classes:
                    t = d.File(c + class_suffix)
                    t.attributes.java_classdir = classdir
                    t.attributes.java_sourcedir = sourcedir
                    t.attributes.java_classname = classname(p + c)
                    tlist.append(t)

        if source_file_based:
            base = f.name[:-len(java_suffix)]
            if pkg_dir:
                t = target[0].Dir(pkg_dir).File(base + class_suffix)
            else:
                pkg_dir = sourcedir.rel_path( f.dir ).replace('.', os.sep)
                if pkg_dir == os.sep:
                    pkg_dir = None

            if pkg_dir:
                p = pkg_dir + os.sep
            else:
                p = ''
            t = target[0].File(p + base + class_suffix)

            t.attributes.java_classdir = classdir
            t.attributes.java_sourcedir = sourcedir
            t.attributes.java_classname = classname(p + base)
            tlist.append(t)

        for t in tlist:
            t.set_specific_source([f])

        full_tlist.extend(tlist)

    return full_tlist, slist
```

The main changes come after the line `if source_file_based:`. This is just a first draft as of right now, but it works. I'll just post the comment I put at the top of JavaFix.py to explain:

```
The original Tools/javac.py couldn't really handle generated
.java files, so this slightly enhanced copy provides a fix.
Simply import the module and call JavaFix.generate(env),
and the Java builder will be remade with an improved emitter
that is better at dealing with generated files.

--Improvements--
When calling env.Java( target, source ), source can now handle
generated files.
--If source is a File node, the output directory structure is
  deduced by copying the directory structure source is in,
  starting from 'com.' If 'com' is not in the directory path,
  SCons will not correctly locate the output node
--If source is a Dir node, SCons will correctly build all .java
  files in the directory tree so long as source is the directory
  containing the start of the package structure
  (e.g. source contains com, and the package structure is com.Foo)
--Functionality concerning non-generated .java files is preserved
```

There are still a few downsides; SCons doesn't pick up on generated inner classes (.class files with a $ in them), and it relies heavily on the directory structure to figure out where the output files go, but at least it's not getting confused and trying to rebuild files it doesn't need to all the time.

I hope this helps bdbaddog or whoever working at SCons will take this bug up to fix. I admit some of my code is a little messy, but it should be understandable.

-Matthew

Comment: If you clean your build tree (scons -c) with your if True: patch does it rebuild properly?

Comment: @bdbaddog No it does not. I guess that was why it was there.